# How to get maven reactor build order for parallel builds?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Maven prints out the reactor build order for sequential builds when i start the mvn command with "-T 4" as parameter. 
I would like to know if it is possible to get the maven reactor build order for parallel builds and if so how to do it.

Comment: The order of build does not change if you are using `-T 4` cause the dependencies between the modules does not change if you run single thread or multiple threads...apart from that why do you need the order?

Comment: We use our own build system which sends build orders to our jenkins. Actually we are sending each project alone and wait for the build to finish. But we could speed it up by sending project groups which could be build parallel.

Comment: Why not letting maven do the work...I don't understand what the advantage of your own build system is? Apart from that it makes your build chain much more complex than needed. Jenkins has very good support for maven build either as Job type or within Pipelines..So you try to go around Maven...which does not really makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

As khmarbaise mentioned. The order of the reactor does not change. If all modules depend on each other in a chain, the build would be the same as the non parallel one. 
Else, Maven will determine the possible parallel paths of building the modules.

Comment: (also for @khmarbaise comment).I'm not agree with this, the build order does change and knowing where it changes or where it will be parallelized can help to spot missing dependencies not involved in the compilation process (unpacked statics or any custom plugin execution needed prior executing another pom). Sorry for the downvote but i can't understand why this is the accepted answer